# What is makeinfo, and how do I get it?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, makefile, grep

I'm trying to build GNU grep, and when I run make, I get:

```
[snip]
/bin/bash: line 9: makeinfo: command not found
```

What is makeinfo, and how do I get it?

(This is Ubuntu, if it makes a difference)

Comment: For those who came here wondering how the subject matter experts below find this stuff: just do `apt-file search bin/makeinfo`

Comment: ```apt search makeinfo``` #(or ```yum search makeinfo```)

Answer (score 480, accepted):

In (at least) Ubuntu when using `bash`, it tells you what package you need to install if you type in a command and its not found in your path. My terminal says you need to install 'texinfo' package.

```
sudo apt-get install texinfo
```

Comment: Just a note that to install the package it is sudo apt-get install **texinfo**. Note that it is teXinfo, not texTinfo which I mistakenly read at first.

Comment: Just for the note - how to get notion about what package contains the utility? i.e. how to get know about texinfo if only I know the name makeinfo.

Comment: You run the command in the terminal `$ makeinfo` and Ubuntu will tell it to you: `he program 'makeinfo' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install texinfo`

Comment: If your shell doesn't give you magical hints like @Tuminoid's does, you can install apt-file and run the commands: `apt-file update && apt-file search makeinfo` Among the results you will see `texinfo: /usr/bin/makeinfo`

Comment: @egor7 The utility telling you the missing command is called `command-not-found`, which you can install with `sudo apt-get install command-not-found`.

Comment: Or, you could use: `dpkg -S /usr/bin/makeinfo`

Comment: Not having the `sudo` on the machine, this might be the worst package to compile yourself...

Comment: Just a note that I needed to install this for a build process that was failing, and which still continued to fail after installing this package.  It turned out that `./configure` had placed a line `MAKEINFO=missing` into the makefiles for the project that was causing them to continue failing; I needed to rerun configure after installing it.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18, at least, make sure you have the `universe` source enabled if you want to install `texinfo`

Comment: This doesn't explain what makeinfo is

Comment: macOS users: `brew install texinfo`

Comment: I can't success. It shows: installed rsyslog package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10.

Answer (score 35):

For Centos , I solve it by installing these packages.

```
yum install texi2html texinfo
```

Dont worry if there is no entry for makeinfo. 
Just run

```
make all
```

You can do it similarly for ubuntu using `sudo`.

Comment: texi2html is strictly speaking, unncecessary. (RHEL6+)

Comment: texi2html is, strictly speaking, unnecessary. (CentOS 7).

Comment: CentOS / Rocky Linux 8: `dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools && dnf install texinfo`

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to use apt-file (i.e. `apt-file search makeinfo`).  It may or may not be installed in your distro by default, but it is a great tool for determining what package a file belongs to.

Answer (score 6):

Need to install texinfo. configure will still have the cache of its results so it will still think makeinfo is missing. Blow away your source and unpack it again from the tarball. run configure then make.

Answer (score 6):

If you build packages from scratch:

- Download a version from here: http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/

  - As of writing, version 5.2 is the latest.
- Learn how to build here: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/texinfo.html

  - LFS project is constantly updating, but texinfo build/install instructions rarely change.

Specifically, if you build `bash` from source, install docs, including man pages, will fail (silently) without `makeinfo` available.

Answer (score 6):

A few words on "what is makeinfo" -- other answers cover "how do I get it" well.

[The section "Creating an Info File"](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/Creating-an-Info-File.html) of the Texinfo manual states that

> `makeinfo` is a program that converts a Texinfo file into an Info file,
>   HTML file, or plain text.

The [Texinfo home page](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/) explains that
Texinfo itself "is the official documentation format of the GNU project" and that it "uses a single source file to produce output in a number of formats, both online and printed (dvi, html, info, pdf, xml, etc.)".

To sum up: Texinfo is a documentation source file format and `makeinfo` is the program that turns source files in Texinfo format into the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

On SuSE linux, you can use the following command to install 'texinfo':

```
sudo zypper install texinfo
```

On my system, it shows it is downloading about 1000 MiB, so make sure you have enough free space.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't show up in your package manager (i.e. `apt-cache search texinfo`) and even `apt-file search bin/makeinfo` is no help, you may have to enable non-free/restricted packages for your package manager.

For ubuntu, `sudo $EDITOR /etc/apt/sources.list` and add `restricted`.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main
```

For debian, `sudo $EDITOR /etc/apt/sources.list` and add `non-free`. You can even have [preferences on package level](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) if you don't want to clutter the package db with non-free stuff.

After a `sudo apt-get udpate` you should find the required package.