# makeinfo package missing in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, package, debian, ubuntu-12.04

Please can anybody give me a answer for this, I have already tried

```
sudo apt-get install makeinfo textinfo texi2html
```

but I still get the error "Unable to find the package."

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is makeinfo, and how do I get it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338317/what-is-makeinfo-and-how-do-i-get-it)

Comment: cross post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/161677/makeinfo-package-not-found-in-12-04

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The package name is `texinfo`. See http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=makeinfo&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise&arch=any or install the `apt-file` search tool locally.